# Run jquery ajax with multi diemnstion array without form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to scrap some elements data from a page using jquery and sending to a php file to save in database what i am doing is:

1. I am creating two dimensional array and want to pass data to php file so I can run a foreach load to save in database:

Error:  Now getting the message : SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in alert box which is alert(errorThrown);

my jquery code is:

```
            function scrape() {

                var info = new Array();
                $("div.clip").each(function (index) {

                    info[index] = {};
                    info[index]['name'] = $(this).find(".fn").text();
                    info[index]['rating'] = $(this).find("span.tinyPush").text();
                    info[index]['review'] = $(this).find("p.description").text();

                });
                console.log(info);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "save_scrap.php",
                    data: {info: info},
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        // Do something before sending request to server
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                        alert(errorThrown);
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#div1").html(data);
                        alert('success!');
                    }
                });
            return false;
        }
```

and i am trying to get it in php file as :

```
print_r($_POST) ;
```

please let me know in comments if you think question is not good or not explaining well.

Thanks.

Comment: You should start by saying what isn't working

Comment: oh sorry. I cant get in the php file to just nothing is showing up so i can do any queries

Comment: Are you getting anything from the `console.log`? If not, it may be because `var info = new Array();` is declared in the `.each` scope. Move that declaration before the `.each` and you should be good.

Comment: I am getting this in console after moving var info = new Array();

[Array[0], Array[0], Array[0], Array[0], Array[0], Array[0], Array[0], Array[0], Array[0], Array[0], $family: function, $constructor: function, each: function, clone: function, clean: function…]0: Array[0]1: Array[0]2: Array[0]3: Array[0]4: Array[0]5: Array[0]6: Array[0]7: Array[0]8: Array[0]9: Array[0]length: 10__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: @RyanWillis I just updated the code. Can you plesae review the code and help me out?

Comment: Change `new Array()` to just `[]` the Array objects are not clean JSON.

Comment: still the same error! Im confused! whats going wrong? also getting the response now but this one error.

in firefox it says: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Got it! thanks! there was an error in my php. (:

Comment: Sweet. I'll add an answer in case someone else needs this.

Answer (score 0):

`var info = new Array();` needs to be

`var info = [];` and it should also be outside the  `.each` scope.